# Prove objects are direct sums in semisimple categories

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to understand the proof in [nLab: semisimple category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semisimple+category#direct_sums_of_simple_objects) and need some help.

Questions:

1. Can someone explain what the copairing is? I am unfamiliar with this term and the usage here does not seem to align with [the definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copairing) given in nLab. It seems to me that this function is only defined on one value - the scalar corresponding to id$_{X_i}$.
2. After doing some googling, I assume that by 'snake equations' they are referring to the [triangle identities](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/triangle+identities) of an adjunction. However, this doesn't seem to make sense - what are the unit, counit and functors in the adjunction here?
3. In equation six, what is $\delta_p^q$? Did they mean $\delta_{pq}$?

I'm hoping that after getting answers for these questions, the rest of the proof will make sense. However, any further explanation of the proof would be appreciated.

Müger in his [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111204) introducing this definition of a semisimple category is not particularly helpful. All he says on this subject is (middle of page 6):

> Then every object $X$ is a finite direct sum of objects in $\{X_i, i \in I\}$ and is determined up to isomorphism by the function $I \to \mathbb Z_+$ given by $i \mapsto N_i^X = \dim\text{Hom}(X,X_i) = \dim\text{Hom}(X_i,X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A copairing, in this context, is literally just a map from $k$ to a tensor product $A\otimes B$. The terminology is perhaps not the optimal choice, but the reason for it is probably that such maps come as the "comultiplications" in coalgebras (and comonoids;) it wouldn't work to say (co)multiplication when $A\neq B$, but "copairing" comes by analogy.
2. A dual to an object $A$ in a monoidal category $C$ can be defined as an adjoint to $A$ in the bicategory with one object which $C$ represents by "delooping" (in the same way that a monoid represents a category with one object.) Thus there are no functors here: you want maps $\eta: k\to A^*\otimes A$ and $\varepsilon: A\otimes A^*\to k$ such that $\varepsilon\otimes A\circ A\otimes \eta=\mathrm{id}_A$, and similarly for the other triangle.
3. Yes, probably.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain further how they define the map $k \to Hom(X_i,V) \otimes Hom(V,X_i)$? It seems like they have only specified its value on only one value: the scalar associated with id$_{X_i}$.

Comment: The identity of $X_i$ corresponds to the multiplicative unit of $k$ (the isomorphism maps composition to multiplication,) so extend by $k$-linearity.